# Avoid multiple rows in join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Suppose that I have three tables, A, B and C:

Table A:

```
C1  C2  Dt
-------------
1   2   8 pm
1   2   10 pm
```

Table B:

```
C1  C2  Ind
-------------
1   2   123
1   2   456
```

Table C:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  Ind
-------------------
1   2   a   b   123
1   2   c   d   123
1   2   e   f   123
1   2   g   h   456
```

As you can see, table B and C have a matching index, while A doesn't. How can I join the three tables so that the first row of A (ordered by the 'dt' column) will only match the rows in C which index is the first in B (ordered by Ind)? The same would apply for the other rows.

What I have tried is to create a simple join:

```
SELECT *
FROM A JOIN B
       ON A.C1 = B.C1
       AND A.C2 = B.C2
JOIN C ON A.C1 = C.C1
       AND A.C2 = C.C2
       AND B.IND = C.IND
```

I know this doesn't work, because each row in A will match all the rows in B and then match all the rows in C. In other words, there is no unique match.

Another approach I have thought made use of two selects:

```
SELECT *
FROM B JOIN (
            SELECT C1, C2, C3, C4, Ind,
                   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY C1, C2, ind ORDER BY C1, C2, ind) AS num_row
            FROM C
            ) table_c
        ON B.IND = table_c.IND
        AND B.C1 = table_c.C1
        AND B.C2 = table_c.C2
JOIN (
        SELECT C1, C2, DT, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DT) AS num_row
        FROM A
        ) table_a
        ON table_a.num_row = table_c.num_row
        AND table_a.C1 = table_c.C1
        AND table_a.C2 = table_c.C2
```

But those tables are very big and every approach that I have tried, would use multiple selects and is very slow. So I was wondering what would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add desired results.

Comment: You should probably add an answer rather than updating the question

Comment: Were you able to find an answer here? If so, please consider marking as such (check box below the votes) and upvoting helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables `A` and `B` have a one to one relationship.  So joining them on a unique id based on the order of each should solve the first part of the problem.

```
create table newA as select rownum as uniq_id, A.* from A order by dt;
create table newB as select rownum as uniq_id, B.* from B order by ind;
select * from newA inner join newB on newA.uniq_id = newB.uniq_id;
```

Then with your new query, join on `C`.

```
select * 
from 
  C 
inner join (select 
             newB.Ind as ind 
            from 
              newA 
              inner join newB on newA.uniq_id = newB.uniq_id) 
          as sub on C.ind = sub.ind
```

I'm sure this could be done with temp tables or strictly in sql but that will depend on your implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER effectively here

```
WITH arn 
     AS (SELECT a.c1, 
                a.c2, 
                "Dt", 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY a.c1, a.c2 
                    ORDER BY "Dt")rn 
         FROM   a), 
     brn 
     AS (SELECT b.c1, 
                b.c2, 
                b."Ind", 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY b.c1, b.c2 
                    ORDER BY b."Ind") rn 
         FROM   b) 
SELECT * 
FROM   arn a 
       inner join brn b 
               ON a.c1 = b.c1 
                  AND a.c2 = b.c2 
                  AND a.rn = b.rn 
       Inner join c
               ON b.c1 = c.c1
                  AND b.c2 = c.c2
                  AND b."Ind" = c."Ind"
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e73cb/1)